# Generating and running migrations in NestJs and TypeORM doesn't work

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I've just been handed a project, and by no means is javascript within my specialization.

I've installed TypeORM globally and tried running:

`npm run typeorm migration:generate -d ./apps/server/src/common/datasource.ts`

config.ts

```
import { dataSource } from './datasource';

export const config = () => {
    try {
        const _config = {
            http: {
                port: process.env.NEST_API_HTTP_PORT,
                ssl: process.env.NEST_API_HTTP_SSL,
                key: process.env.NEST_API_HTTP_KEY,
                cert: process.env.NEST_API_HTTP_CERT,
                cors: process.env.NEST_API_HTTP_CORS,
                globalPrefix: process.env.NEST_API_HTTP_GLOBAL_PREFIX,
            },

            db: dataSource,

            secrets: {
                pwdsalt: process.env.NEST_API_SECRETS_PWDSALT,
                jwt: process.env.NEST_API_SECRETS_JWT,
            },

            rules_engine: {
                url: process.env.RULES_ENGINE_URL,
                globalPrefix: process.env.RULES_ENGINE_HTTP_GLOBAL_PREFIX,
            },
        };

        return configSchema.validateSync(_config);
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error((err as ValidationError).message);
    }
};
```

datasource.ts

```
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";

export const dataSource = new DataSource({
    type: 'postgres',
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: Number(process.env.DATABASE_PORT),
    name: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
    username: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    synchronize: Boolean(process.env.DATABASE_ENABLE_SYNC)
});
```

package.json - scripts:

```json
"typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js",
```

It just responds with

```
Couldn't find tsconfig.json. tsconfig-paths will be skipped
'missing required argument: dataSource'
```

I've tried changing paths, but also executable from ts-node to typeorm and others.

**Worth noting: it's in an Nx monorepo project and uses NestJs**

Answer (score 0):

NestJS/nx version missing ;)

But, long story short, this is what works for me on NestJS 10, nx 17.3.0:

1. Create a target `typeorm` in `project.json` (**not** `package.json`!), with a command:

```bash
TS_NODE_PROJECT="{PATH_RELATIVE_TO_MONOREPO_ROOT}" && \
  node && \
  --require ts-node/register && \
  --require tsconfig-paths/register && \
  {PATH_RELATIVE_TO_MONOREPO_ROOT}/mode_modules/typeorm/cli.js && \
  --config {PATH_RELATIVE_TO_MONOREPO_ROOT}/{PATH_TO_TYPEORM_CONFIG}
```

JSON should look like this:

```json
{
  "build": { "...": "..."},
  "migrate": {
    "command": "{COMMAND_FROM_ABOVE}"
  }
}
```

2. Run it from monorepo root `nx run {backend_name}:{migrate}`
3. Also, synchronization wouldn't work, because that'd mean importing from application's entities, and they won't be available to TypeORM CLI ran from outside of application environment. You need to find a way to build entities index manually :)
4. Also, huge chance that if you run `nx run backend:migrate --somearg "foo"`, arguments won't get properly parsed by nx. So it's good to create a few targets (for running, rolling down migrations, etc.) in `project.json`. Or creating a custom executor for that.

---

5. Moving up to MikroORM.